# ng-if doesn't work if condition text contains space in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I was trying to set values into Angular js Ui grid based on the row.entity values.To do that i have created cellTemplate that check the row values and based on values i did some text styling.

**Code Snippet**

```
var statusTemplate='<div>
<span class="txt-color-yellow" ng-if=row.entity.status.name=="Draft">{{row.entity.status.name}}</span>
<span class="txt-color-orange" ng-if=row.entity.status.name==[
    "AwaitingReview"]>{{row.entity.status.name}} </span><span
    class="txt-color-green" ng-if=row.entity.status.name=="Reviewed">{{row.entity.status.name}}
</span><span class="txt-color-blue" ng-if=row.entity.status.name==[ "Ready ForScripting"]>{{row.entity.status.name}}</span><span
    class="txt-color-brown" ng-if=row.entity.status.name==[ "Awating
    ScriptReview"]>{{row.entity.status.name}}</span><span
    class="txt-color-green" ng-if=row.entity.status.name==[ "ScriptReviewed"]>{{row.entity.status.name}}</span><span
    class="txt-color-green" ng-if=row.entity.status.name=="Closed">{{row.entity.status.name}}</span>
```

';

But the problem was in `ng-if` when trying to check text values with spaces it throws an exception saying `Unterminated quote at columns 25-34 ["Awaiting] in expression [row.entity.status.name==["Awaiting]. etc...`.

Please let me know how can i check the text with spaces in ng-if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it in all div where write like string pass in the single `''` and condition write in double quote `""`

```
ng-if="row.entity.status.name=='Draft'"
```

Comment: also i had to add \ in string. `ng-if="row.entity.status.name==\'Awaiting Review\'" `

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the condition in `"`. So following should help.

```
ng-if="row.entity.status.name=='Draft'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have quote for ng-if, Try this `ng-if="row.entity.status.name==[\"Awaiting Review}\"]"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ng-if="row.entity.status.name==\'Draft\'"

Comment: Please explain _why_ it is the answer to the question. And place 4 spaces before your code to create a code block. This will increase the quality of your answer.